# How to include all output from an R Markdown chunk in one block?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

When I evaluate a code chunk using knitr in RMarkdown, there are blank spaces separating code from output.

For example, if I evaluate the following chunk:

```
# I want to remove the white separations from the following chunk output

1+1

2+4
```

Then I receive the following output in my document (notice the blank white lines)

[image]

What I really want is this, where both the code and the output is contained in one formatted code block.

```
# I want to remove the white separations from the following chunk output

1+1

## [1] 2

2+4

## [1] 6
```

How can I get the chunk output to not have the blank white spaces?

Note: I do *not* want all of the output to come after the code as would happen if I included the chunk option `results = "hold"`. I need the output from each line to come right after the code that generated the line.

Comment: did you try `collapse=TRUE`?

Comment: That did it! Thanks @hrbrmstr